# AVAssetWriter: specify key frames

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mp4, avassetwriter

I'm using an `AVAssetWriter` on iOS to encode an MP4 video.  I'm currently passing data in with an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`, but I'm flexible on that front.

How can I specify which of my input frames are key frames?

Currently, I can control the number of key frames (or make all frames key frames) by setting `AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey`, but my encoded video is a straightforward slideshow-with-transitions, and I'd like to ensure key frames at the main images without sacrificing compression.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `CMSampleBufferRef`s (via `CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(…)` to pass in to your `AVAssetWriterInput` directly (instead of going through an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`), you can then use `CMSetAttachment(…)` to set `kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_ForceKeyFrame` to `kCFBooleanTrue` on your frame to ensure that it will become a key frame.

A potential downside to moving away from `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` is that you lose the memory efficiency that comes with having a shared pixel buffer pool.

If the memory efficiency is important, you might want to consider looking into `VideoToolbox` and `VTCompressionSession` instead. `VTCompressionSession` is more complex than `AVAssetWriter*` is, but also exposes the pixel buffer pool that's used internally.

If you do go down this route, you'll want to use the `kVTEncodeFrameOptionKey_ForceKeyFrame` key set to `kCFBooleanTrue` as a frame attribute when submitting a frame to `VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(…)` for compression.